# synchronous scrolling in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement synchronous scrolling in ng-repeat

Explanation :

I have locations on the top of page horizontally and products in vertically.

```
 L1 L2 L3 L4 L5

P1
P2
p3
p4
```

based on product click have to display the information for the all the  locations.

ex: when the user clicked on p1, p1 will expand call it as expandable div 
and display the information.

```
  L1 L2 L3 L4 L5



 P1  1  1  1  1  1  1
        2  2  2  2  2
        3  3  3     3
           4  4     4
              5     5

 P2
 P3
 P4
```

Now the problem: 
I have provided scrolling for the product expandable div. Now I would like to have the sync scrolling for the all the divs

```
        <div class="workloadInfo" ng-class="cardclass" ng-show="isRelavent({{p.Id}})" >
<div class="designerContainer " data-ng-repeat="process in processInfo  | filter:{'ProductId':p.Id}:true | filter:{'ProcessLocationsId':locations.Id}:true" >
<div ng-repeat="d in details | filter:{'Location':locations.Id}:true | filter :{'Product':p.Id}" >
<div  ng-repeat="name in d.Lname">
<a title="{{name.Category}}-{{name.Title}}" class="{{name.Category}} designerBox"></a>
</div>
                                           </div>

                                       </div>  

                                                   </div>
```